# Selenium vba, How to avoid open "_blank" link to new tab

Tags: html, vba, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

HTML
    `<a target="_blank" id="mylink" herf="www.google.com">google</a>`

VBA
    `driver.FindElementById("mylink").Click`

How can I have the "driver" object refer to the new browser TAB or just open the link in the same browser TAB instead of opening into a new browser TAB even the link has a target="_blank" attribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I never used selenium, but I think you should be able to get `href` attribute value and open that as a link, something like:

```
driver.get( driver.FindElementById("mylink").getAttribute("href") );
```

Comment: `Call driver.get(driver.FindElementById("mylink").Attribute("href"))`